# Calendar will not display

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

When I view calendars on iOS, all can see is an "i" with a circle around it.  If I click the i, it just brings up the calendar color.

I can not view any of the calendar items.

The same calendar on my mac is working.

Answer (score 1):

NEVER MIND!  I realized that it was simply updating the new data I added to the calendar.  It took 1 day to do that for some reason.  I reconnected to the mac and synced it again, and it is finally working.